# Is there a way to speed up permutations of permutations?

Tags: python, permutation

I’m trying to generate permutations of 5 numbers from a list (numset).  Then I choose two of the five numbers and test them (another permutation).  This appears to work but is very inefficient and time consuming with a large numset list (100k+ entries).  I’m wondering if there is a way to optimize this?

```
from itertools import permutations

numbers2 = []

# Get all permutations of length 5 so we have five numbers to test.
numbers5 = permutations(numset, 5)

def testfive():
  # Choose two of the numbers from the 5 number list and test them.
  for i in list(numbers5):
      numbers2 = permutations(numbers5, 2)
      for x in list(numbers2):
        if (test(x)!=True):
          break
      # Do something if the test is successful.

testfive()
```

Here is how this should operate:

I start with a large number set (numset) like: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 …]

I pick five numbers, without repeating: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

Then I pick two of these: [2, 4] or [2, 6] or [2, 8] and so on.

Then I start over with five more numbers: [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]

I do this over, and over, and over again.  I’m using Colab, and it runs out of RAM.  I know this is a brute force way of going through numbers, but I’m wondering if there is a tool to optimize this that I’m missing?

Comment: You're creating new permutations from your complete set of permutations - not choosing two of five numbers; you're creating a whole new set of permutations of how you can pick two of the original permutations; and you're doing this _for each permutation in numbers5_. I don't understand what the first `for i in list(numbers5)` is trying to achieve. It'd be helpful if you could explain what you're actually trying to do instead; since your code doesn't really match what you say you want to do; What `test` does is also important for complexity.

Comment: If you do the math of how many ways you can combine 100k+ entries into a selection of five entries, you'll soon discover that the number of permutations grow very high. Usually you won't have to convert these permutations to a list either, you can safely lazily evaluate them.

Comment: `for i in list(numbers5)` is intended to loop through each item (a list of 5 numbers) from the first permutation output.  My “test” simply looks to see if the two numbers match a set of criteria.  That portion is fairly quick and simple.  

One possibility I had considered would be to filter the first permutation output to reduce the number of permutations.

Comment: It's not clear why you need first permutations with 5 elements. I'd say to generate only permutations with 2 elements, but as I said, it's not clear what are you need to achieve.

Comment: Also it's not clear why are you trying to filter permutations instead of generating directly only valid sequences.

Comment: Like MatsLindh said, remove the `list()` calls, for starters – `for i in numbers5:`. You’ll at least not run out of memory that way. Beyond that, you need to describe the actual problem you’re trying to solve with this program to get a useful answer, because there’s no room to optimize “follow this exact unjustified procedure”.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would avoid calling the `list` function because that would compute the list, load the whole list into your RAM and iterate through it **after** it was created and `numbers5` never gets deleted in your code.

Here is some (pseudo)code to show you a better way of doing this. Everything should be computed **when it's needed** and discarded after its usage. A generator does exactly this, like explained [here](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/). [`permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) is a generator because it yields one result on every `next()` call. And I assume you want to select two numbers **randomly**:

```
from itertools import permutations
from random import choices

#numset = range(8) # for testing

def testfive():
  # Choose two of the numbers from the 5 number list and test them.
  for l in permutations(numset, 5): # is discarded after use
        if test(choices(l, k=2)):
          # Success
      
testfive()
```

But as a side note: If you do this with 100k entries, then you have 100000! / (100000-5)! = 9.999 000 035 × 10^24 5-permutations.
For further optimization, you could take a look at [Cython](https://cython.org/). It can be [much faster](https://www.cardinalpeak.com/blog/faster-python-with-cython-and-pypy-part-2).